# Twitter Intent: Related account doesn't show up in Tweet

Tags: twitter

Why doesn't the related account show up from this URL?

http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=HeyNow&related=HowardStern&hashtags=bababooey

The result is this:

> HeyNow #bababooey

But I expect it to be:

> HeyNow @HowardStern #bababooey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the variable `related` you have to use the variable `via`. Try this:

https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=HeyNow&via=HowardStern&hashtags=bababooey

More information can you find in the [documentation of the twitter web intents](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents#tweet-intent). From the Documentation:

Variable **via**:

A screen name to associate with the Tweet. The provided screen name will be appended to the end of the tweet with the text: "via @username" "Via" will be translated to the proper locality of the posting user, if supported. Potentially drives new followers to the target account.

Variable **related**:

Suggest accounts related to the your content or intention by comma-separating a list of screen names. After Tweeting, the user will be encouraged to follow these accounts.

Greetings.